# Listening for messages in Erlang

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing

I'm trying to write a function that will make a process wait in a receive loop and pattern match on input to create more processes.

```
-module(masterNode).

%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([listen/0]).



%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================


listen() ->
    receive
        {userNodeName, createNode} ->
            spawn(userNode, listen, [userNodeName]),
            io:format("User Node Created!~n"),
            listen();
        {_, createNode} ->
            spawn(userNode, listen, ["Anonymous"]),
            io:format("Anonymous User Node Created!~n"),
            listen();       
        _ ->
            io:format("Invalid syntax!.~n")
    end.
```

When I try to spawn a masterNode into a variable from the command line, I get this error:

```
5> mn = spawn(masterNode, listen, []).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <0.44.0>
```

However, if I don't try to store it into a variable, I have no problem:

```
6> spawn(masterNode, listen, []).     
<0.47.0>
```

What I'm trying to do is run the listen command using this masterNode variable to activate the pattern matching and create more processes via another module(userNode). Like so:

```
mn ! {userNode1, createNode}. %Create a userNode process called userNode1
```

I'm new to Erlang so I may be going about this the wrong way. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also new to Erlang, but perhaps it could be as simple as this:

`mn` is not a variable, it is an atom. As such, when you do `atom = statement` you are doing a comparison and not an assignment. Try renaming it Mn or Pid (which is used in most tutorials).

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks!